# Can a polarizing beam splitter cube be used to replace two polarizers?

Tags: optics, polarization, geometric-optics

I have a design for a setup to look at the light reflecting off the back of the human retina. I would like to remove any specular reflection that occurs at the cornea. At the moment the idea is to use two polarizers to remove the specular reflection as seen in the diagram below.

[image: Dual Polarizers]

Can a polarizing beam cube be used to replace both polarizers? I am aware that beam cubes have a specific direction they work in, see the beamsplitter below.

[image: Polarizing beam cube]

But what happens if i send unpolarized light from the laser into the S face of the polarized beam cube, will it reflect S polarized light only into the optical path and allow me to replace both polarizers? like in the final diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It will work as you suggest as far as your diagram goes, assuming that the retina is going to depolarise the light. Would it not be better to better to illuminate the eye with unpolarsied light since the depolarisation is not going to that efficient? Then you would be putting less laser power into the eye.

The beam splitters are made by cementing two prisms together, one of the prisms has a coating on it that reflects one of the linear states. According to Thorlabs it is better to use the prism with the coating on as the entrance to the beamsplitter, however any face can be used. I suspect you'd get slightly a worse extinction ratio if you via the other prism but I use them all the time and I've never noticed it.

Comment: I think the reason to polarize the input is to be able to remove *all* the corneal reflection which, being specular, maintains the input polarization.

Comment: Yes it is to remove all corneal reflection